# Redirecting to another resource after creating in rails admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-admin

Imagine I have this too models: Invoice and PaymentOrder.
My business logic makes a new PaymentOrder when you create a new Invoice.

So I need to redirect the user to the newly created PaymentOrder after a user creates an Invoice using Rails Admin.

Any ideas ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show the code that you already have?

Comment: All the CRUD is being managed by RailsAdmin, no custom code yet. only Model callbacks.

Comment: Looks like you would want to override the `create` action. See if `rails_admin` lets you do that. Or add a `create` like custom action which might let you redirect - https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-action. Definitely this is not a first class feature in Rails Admin.

Answer (score 1):

I would override create action.  Here is how I would do controller

```
  register_instance_option :controller do
    Proc.new do
      object.create
      flash[:notice] = "created #{@object.name}"
      redirect_to show_path
    end
  end
```